# How to compare keys in a dictionary and see if one key contains the other?

Tags: python, list, loops, time-complexity

Here is a dict of words as keys,

```
count_dict = {
    'apple':2,
    'pie': 1,
    'pi':1,
    'applepie':1
}
```

and if one long word contains another short word, add the count of long word to the short one. Which means the result is:

```
{
  'apple':3,
  'pie': 2,
  'pi':3,
  'applepie':1
}
```

The most easy way is using a simple loop,

```
for i in list:
    for j in list:
        if len(i) < len(j) and i in j:
            count_dict[i] += 1
```

but the time complexity is **O(n^2)**, that cost too much time.
Is there any way to reduce complexity to solve this problem?

Comment: in order to do what you describe, one **has to** check every key against every other and thus, the complexity is bound to be O(n^2) imo. I would be very surprised if there was another way.

Comment: what do you call `list` in your code?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You could build a suffix-tree from the keys (takes O(n) time), after that checking if a key appears in the tree takes O(m) time where `m` is the number of characters in the key,. Also: it is possible to obtain all keys that contain that given key in this way. So the algorithm would take O(n) + O(n*m) and m is probably some constant.

Comment: The problem seems to have a different solution depending on the processing order - is that right?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta should point out that this will be worse for some inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in O(n) time using a [Suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), in particular see the [generalized suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Generalized_suffix_tree). You first create the Suffix tree of all the keys, after that you can iterate over each key and for each one search it in the suffix tree (takes O(len(key)) time).

After you found the key in your tree you can find all the sub-trees of your key and those are exactly the longer keys that contain your key, so you can take each of them and update your dict.

If `m` is constant (say your keys are at most 100 characters long) then the number of sub-trees will be constant too (at most a subtree of height 100) and so the whole thing takes O(n) time.

---

Instead of a suffix tree you can use a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) which is a more space efficient version of this type of data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit better than O(n^2) but big O notation is not my strong suit. Have a look:

```
count_dict = {
    'apple':2,
    'pie': 1,
    'pi':1,
    'applepie':1
}

keys = list(count_dict.keys())
res_dict = {}
for i, k1 in enumerate(keys):
    res_dict[k1] = res_dict.setdefault(k1, count_dict[k1])
    for k2 in keys[i+1:]:
        if k1 in k2:
            res_dict[k1] += count_dict[k2]
        elif k2 in k1:
            res_dict[k2] = res_dict.setdefault(k2, count_dict[k2]) + count_dict[k1]
        else:
            continue
print(res_dict)  # -> {'apple': 3, 'pie': 2, 'pi': 3, 'applepie': 1}
```

Comment: This is still O(n^2) - you have two nested loops that traverse the keys linearly.

Comment: @BartoszKP but the second does not traverse the entire list.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the function asymptotically looks the same as n^2: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(n-i)+for+i+%3D+1+to+n

Comment: You are right in that it is still O(n^2) but it is faster than the standard double loop and the [gains increase as n grows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+n(n%2B1)%2F2,+n%5E2+from+n+%3D+1+to+100).